# Determine whether a given function is a pseudorandom generator/function

Tags: pseudo-random-function, pseudo-random-generator

I am trying to solve the following three tasks (for exam practice, not as a homework):

1. Define $ : \{0,1\}^* \rightarrow \{0,1\}^*$ by $G(x_1,...,x_n) = _1 \oplus _2,_1,⋅⋅⋅,x_n.$ Prove that this $G$ is not a pseudorandom generator.
2. Let $G$ be a pseudorandom generator, and define $G'(x_1, ..., x_n) = G(x_1, ..., x_n)|(x_1 \vee x_2)$. Is $G'$ a pseudorandom generator?
3. Define $ : \{0,1\}^* × \{0,1\}^* \rightarrow \{0,1\}^*$ as follows: $_{_1,...,_} (_1,..., _) = \bigoplus_i _ _$, where $_, _ \in \{0,1\}^*$ (Note that, different from the usual convention, $F$ takes an n-bit key and an n-bit input, but has only a single-bit output). Prove that this  is not a pseudorandom function.

My guesses are:

1. Not a pseudorandom generator since a distinguisher can always distinguish G(s) from a truly random string because the first bit of G(s) is always equal to the XOR of the second and third bit.
2. Not a pseudorandom generator because a distinguisher could simply check whether the last bit of the string equals $x_1 \vee x_2$ and could thus distinguish G(s) from a truly random string.
3. I cannot determine how to solve this.

Are my guesses correct? Can someone provide an idea for 3?

Comment: 1 is correct. 2 is not, because the distinguisher is not given the seed, so it cannot compute $x_1 \vee x_2$.

Comment: And for 3, I don't understand your notation.

Comment: 3- the intuition should be that the one-time pad (i.e. XOR'ing bits) is no longer secure if the 'secret randomness' (the $k_i$ here) is re-used. (Focus on the case of $x_i, k_i\in\{0,1\}$. Among other approaches to this.. consider an Adv that asks for many samples $x_i$ in different 'directions' e.g. $x_1 = (1, 0, 0...), x_2 =(0, 1, 0, ...), x_3 = (0, 0, 1, ..), ...$ then once it's saturated the space, queries once more anywhere.)

Comment: @fkraiem, regarding 2. So this is a PRG? Or it is not but my solution is incorrect? regarding 3. I have added a sentence that was part of the original question

Comment: @DanielApon I'm not sure whether I fully understand your solution. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: I was saying that your solution is incorrect, but if you want to know, no, it's not a PRG. (The fact that this construction is significantly simpler than standard ones is already a good indication that it is not.)

Comment: @fkraiem But how could I prove that, i.e. what would be a possible way to distinguish G'(s) from a random string?

Comment: Hint: it is sufficient to consider the last bit of the string (without referring to anything else).

Comment: @fkraiem: but the last bit will always be 0 or 1, independent of whether we look at G'(s) or a random string. How could I exploit that it's $x_1 \vee x_2$ when I don't know $x_1, x_2$?

Comment: @Lemon: Hint: For (2), if it were a XOR, you could not so easily distinguish. But OR is different.

Comment: @NeilSlater: The only thing I can think of is that OR is 1 most of the time. But does that really help in distinguishing strings if the other string is random?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fully solved the questions now.

1. Not a pseudorandom generator since the first bit of $G(s)$ is always equal to the XOR of the second and third bit, i.e. a distinguisher can easily tell $G(s)$ apart from a truly random string $r$.
2. Not a pseudorandom generator. We can for example construct a distinguisher $D$ that, on input of a string $w$, outputs 1 if and only if the final bit is 0. If $w$ is uniformly distributed then the final bit is 0 with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ but if $w = G(s)$ for a uniformly distributed seed s  the final bit will be 0 with probability $\frac{1}{4}$.
3. Not a pseudorandom function. A distinguisher D could tell $F_k$ apart from a truly random function $f$ in the following way: Given access to an oracle $W$, D queries $W(0...0)$. If $W = F_k$ then the result will always be 0, but if $W$ is a random function then it should be 0 only with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.